# python import beginner confusion

Tags: python, import

I'm a beginner python user and am slighlty confused over the way modules are imported.

I've attached a screen shot to make it more clear what i'm asking.

I have the following code taken from djangoproject.com:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

As the import statement refers to the folder named 'models' does this mean every module inside the 'models' folder is being imported into the session?

If so is models.Model a class found in one of those modules? If yes then why am i unable to find this class in any of the files? I've done a search for 'class Model(' in all of the files and can't find it.

[image]

Comment: It's in `base.py`: [`class Model(metaclass=ModelBase):`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py)

Comment: By importing a module you basically call the __init__ file of the module, if this includes the imports of the individual files then yes, but if it is empty then no. This is used to setup any module related code. https://pythontips.com/2013/07/28/what-is-__init__-py/

Comment: Check this line `from django.db.models.base import DEFERRED, Model  # isort:skip` in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/__init__.py

It's importing `Model` from `django.db.models.base`.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module like this, provided `module.__init__.py` is empty, nothing is getting imported.

If you can do something like:

```py
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

then it means that `CharField` was either defined in `__init__.py` or somehow imported explicitly in `module.__init__.py`

So, to answer your question what was actually imported after you had called `from django.db import models` you need to check `module.__init__.py`

You can find more information here: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)
and here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html